# Complexity of MongoDB queries - sort versus two queries

Tags: mongodb, big-o

I need to do two queries on two collections to the mongodb.

One Database is the E-Mail Message the other is the E-Mail-Template.

I need to send several emails with several templates, so I iterate over all mails and check wich template is assigned to them, then look up the template.

I could do it like

1. Find Mail
2. Find Template for each mail

or sort it and check if the template changed:

1. Find Mail and Sort by Template (Could be indexed)
2. If the new template is not the old template, find the template

which approach has less complexity? There are a lot more emails than templates. (1000 emails per hour vs. a few hundred templates in total)

I have heared that a find-query takes O(log(n)+m) where n is amount of data in the collection and m is the amount of entries that will be fetched .

Answer (score 0):

what i could propose in this case will be based on:

```
email {
    _id,
    /*all other fields*/
    templateId
}

db.emails.aggregate([{
            $match : {
                "emailIsEnt" : false
            }
        }, {
            $lookup : {
                from : emailTemplates,
                localField : templateId,
                foreignField : _id,
                as : "emailTemplate"
            }
        }
    ])
```

this query will get templates for each `matched` email, so there is no need to do an extra query and database engine will provide results (once template will be read from disk it will be stored in page in memory, so internal cache will kick-off to support that)